# How do I specify a hash algorithm in Xamarin?

Tags: c#, xamarin

Programmed in Visual Studio 2019 on Windows 10.
RFC 2898 encoding process from a .NET Framowork 4.7.2 project. to Xamarin.Form (.NET Standard 2.0) .
The original processing is as follows

```
var salt = "abcdefg";
var passWord = "password";
var iterations = 5;
var saltbyte = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8. GetBytes(salt);
var Rfc2898 = new System.Security.Cryptography. Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passWord, saltbyte, iterations, System.Security.Cryptography. HashAlgorithmName.SHA256);
```

Porting it will result in an error in Xamarin, because you can't specify a hash algorithm. You can't specify a hash algorithm.

```
var Rfc2898 = new System.Security.Cryptography. Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passWord, saltbyte, iterations);
```

How do I specify a hash algorithm in Xamarin?

Translated with [www.DeepL.com/Translator](http://www.DeepL.com/Translator) (free version)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like .NET Standard 2.0 doesn't provide the constructor with the `HashAlgorithmName` argument. It is however present in .NET Standard 2.1. You can easily change your library to use .NET Standard 2.1.

Otherwise, you will have to do that platform specifically instead. Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android do have the constructor available.

So I would create a service to hash your passwords:

```
public interface IPasswordHasher
{
    byte[] GetHashedPassword(string password, string salt, int keySize);
}
```

Then implement this on both Android and iOS and register it as a [Xamarin.Forms DependencyService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction) instance:

```
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text.Encoding;
using Xamarin.Forms;

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(MyAwesomeProject.iOS.Services.PasswordHasher))]

namespace MyAwesomeProject.iOS.Services
{
    public class PasswordHasher : IPasswordHasher
    {
        public byte[] GetHashedPassword(string password, string salt, int keySize)
        {
            var saltbyte = UTF8.GetBytes(salt);
            var rfc2898 = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, saltbyte, 1000, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256);
            return rfc2898.GetBytes(keySize);
        }
    }
}
```

Then when you need to use it as:

```
var bytes = DependencyService.Get<IDeviceOrientationService>().GetHashedPassword("password", "abcdefg", 20);
```

I highly recommend that you use more than 5 iterations for your PBKDF2 key derivation. The default is 1000, the higher the better. Of course on mobile, you may hit a performance limitation, but 5 is *way* too low.

Comment: Hello Mr. Cheesebaron!
Thank you for your comment and code samples.
I upgraded to .NET Standard 2.1 and it worked fine.
I was able to verify the operation and confirm that it works perfectly.
Thank you very much. It was very helpful.

Comment: If my answer helped you. Please mark the answer as Accepted and consider up-voting it as well.